# Error with Excel destination connection manager using SSI

Tags: excel, ssis, oledb

I have to move data from a OLE DB Source ( data contained into a table) to an excel destination. This file contains only the headers that are equal to those of my dB Table. When I connect to my excel file I would expect to have some choice when I go to select the way to insert data but I have this issue returned :
[image]

In other words, even if in my connection manager is linked to the template xlsx file in the destination folder SSIS cannot return me some sheet to make the mapping. Anyone knows how to fix this issue?
I followed the instructions in this video, but without success: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwUhHIpRoIA&t=376s)

Thank You in advance

PS: I CANNOT SHARE DATA SO DO NOT ASK FOR THEM

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using? Not all versions support. Xlsx files. Try saving as an older version of excel (.Xls) and see if you can read that

Comment: Just fixed! I used excel 97-2003 to save my template file and SSIS read it. Thank you for your support!

Comment: Yeah, the Excel format you define in the connection manager has to match the format of the Excel file. Any time SSIS tells you it can't find a Sheet in the Excel file, it's because SSIS is expecting a different format.

Comment: excel 97-2003 format fits very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would absolutely need to use .xlsx Microsoft Excel 2016, and you don't want to settle for older formats, you can do that if you install 32-bit driver 
Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920 (AccessDatabaseEndine.exe 77MB). 
After downloading, install it from cmd window using command: 
AccessDatabaseEndine /quiet 
It will allow you to select Excel version Microsoft Excel 2016 in Excel Connection Manager.